# Changes in the printout of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95ezN/1/)

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("example"));
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "<span id='signature'>Signature : <input type='text'></span>";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
     }
</script>
```

I want to add a signature box in the print out section i.e. the printout window and not on the browser window. Although I did add it, I wanted to add CSS so that it is at the bottom of the print out page. I tried giving it an id and adding the CSS to that Id, but it didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why use javascript? Use css to hide stuff you don't want printed ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/95ezN/852/))

```
@media print {
  div:not(#printThis), hr {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: okay.. but if i want something on the printout window and not on the browser window then????

Comment: Then use `@media screen { #printThis { display: none; } }`

Comment: dude i want to add a signature box on the print out window and dont want it on the browser window

Comment: bro the signature box is not moving

Comment: Moving where? What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome and the print preview is showing stuff as expected.

Comment: i want the signature box at the bottom of the print out window

Comment: You're killing me man... the problem is the signature block is a `span`... you can't add a `margin-top` to a span - https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/avvsoLLw/2/